# Unmount user home directory in a delayed background process after logging out

Tags: mount, background-process, unmounting, delay

The home directory of user `bob` is mounted by a superuser from elsewhere.

`bob` himself is a sudoer, he is logged in and is happily using his mounted home directory. He finishes his work and wants to run a script which will log him out *and* unmount his home directory.

He tries:

```
cd / # switch to a directory other than /home/bob to avoid keeping it busy
bash -c 'sleep 5 && sudo umount /home/bob </dev/null &>/dev/null & disown
gnome-session-quit --no-prompt
```

He gets logged out but then, when `alice` logs in (also a sudoer), she sees `bob`'s home directory still mounted after a while. Apparently, the `umount` command fails for some reason.

How can `bob` reliably unmount it upon logging out?

Comment: The home directory is probably still in use by the session. Perhaps something like `echo umount /home/bob | sudo at now + 1 minutes` will work?

Comment: my administrative gut feeling is that it's not Bob who should be in charge of unmounting his home directory (because, he might simply forget to do that). The same party that mounted it should be responsible for unmounting it. and that's exactly why modern Linux has user session management mechanisms that can be hooked (PAM, and very relevantly, systemd-logind).

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is inconvenient to require Alice to log in after Bob just to unmount his directory. An analogy is car rental: when you pick up a rental car, someone needs to handle the paperwork, check your driver's license, hand you the keys. When you drop off, you just leave the car and the keys in a designated place _yourself_ and walk away.

Comment: why would anyone need to login to do this manually? that **really** sounds  illogical. And your analogy is nice, because you're assuming that a mounted directory is like a car key – which Bob can forget to throw in. You are designer of your own car here, that car doesn't need to have any key to throw in.

Comment: The logical thing to happen here is: 1. Someone enables the login for Bob on a machine. 2. Bob logs in 2.1. The system automatically mounts bob's home directory 3. Bob does what he needs to do within his session 4. Bob logs out and thus ends his session 4.1. the system automatically unmounts Bob's home directory.

Comment: From a SysAdmin (50+ years, made many mistakes), you should `umount` the user's `$HOME` with "a superuser from elsewhere". She should start a background task that repeatedly checks `sudo lsof +D /home/bob`, and `umount`ing `/home/bob`. Both `bob` and `alice` are, in this context, **users**,  you cannot trust their actions. Cannot.

Comment: This seems like a great situation for using [autofs](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/autofs.html). See also [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/mount-nfs-filesystems-autofs).